# string values are automatically changed to double values

Tags: java, object, arraylist, gson

After parsing an object the string values are automatically changed to double values.
Any workaround for the same

```
JSONObject elementInfo = obj.getElementInfo();
System.out.println("get elementInfo ---> "+elementInfo.get("info"));

//mapping
ArrayList<Object> getEle = gson.fromJson((String) elementInfo.get("info"), ArrayList.class);
System.out.println("After mapping getele----> "+getEle);
```

Result

```
get elementInfo ---> [{noOfBins=2, indices=[1, 3]}, {noOfBins=3, indices=[2]}]
After mapping getele----> [{noOfBins=2.0, indices=[1.0, 3.0]}, {noOfBins=3.0, indices=[2.0]}]
```

Even after mapping how will I get the exact value?
Need to get it as

```
[{noOfBins=2, indices=[1, 3]}, {noOfBins=3, indices=[2]}]
```

Comment: I don't see any String in your `elementInfo` Json. A String in JSON is like `"2"` or `'2'`, without the quotes, this is a numeric

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, string shoubld be contained in double quotes, that means `"4"` instead of `4` .